# Combining 'Excel-like' behavior and updating the model when focus leaves my JTable

Tags: java, swing, focus, jtable, tablecelleditor

I had a request for JTable functionality that would allow data entry more like in Excel. If the user types in a cell, the previous value is replaced by the new value and one can navigate between rows and columns using arrow keys.

I found several solutions to this problem and implemented one.

I was then given an additional requirement- if the user clicks outside the table, the cell that data was being entered into is updated (editing stops).

I suspect I am just missing something, but my attempts to implement both requirements have failed.

1. I have a custom cell editor that listens for focusLost ans stops cell editing. This works if I double click in the table and then click outside the table. But if I just typed a number in a cell, this method doesn't run.
2. tableMe.setSurrendersFocusOnKeystroke(true); This a) results in my losing the first keystroke and b) puts me in the editor, so I can;t used the right and left arrow keys to move out the cell.
3. I added a FocusListener on the table. Then, I can just type a number in a cell and navigate to another cell, but I can never get into the editor. A double-click immediately stops the edit. I thought I could find some difference between when I was 'really' editing (have a cursor in the editor window) and when I have just typed a number in the cell. What I have tried so far (isEditing() always comes up true, hasFocus() always comes up false) does not work.

Can anyone point me a solution for this? My attempts are below. I commented out the false starts, but they are there so you can see what I tried.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

class ExcelTableTest extends JFrame
{
    public static final Color activeDark  = new Color(230, 185, 184);
    public static final Color activeLight = new Color(244, 233, 233);

    private MyJTable      tableMe;
    private MyTableModel  modelMe;
    private JTextField    textMe;
    private JScrollPane   scrollTable;

    private String[]   tableHeaders = { "Column 1", "Column 2" };
    private Object[][] tableData    = new Object[ tableHeaders.length ][ 4 ];

    ExcelTableTest()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
        modelMe  = new MyTableModel(tableData, tableHeaders );
        tableMe  = new MyJTable(modelMe);
        tableMe.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        TableColumn column = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < tableHeaders.length; i++)
        {
           column = tableMe.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
           column.setCellRenderer( new MyCellRenderer()   );
           column.setCellEditor(   new NumberCellEditor() );
        }
        tableMe.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
//      tableMe.addFocusListener( new MyFocusListener() );
//      tableMe.setSurrendersFocusOnKeystroke(true);

//      modelMe.addTableModelListener(new MyTableModelListener());
        scrollTable = new JScrollPane(tableMe);
        scrollTable.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
            ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollTable.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(
            ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scrollTable.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,150));

        textMe = new JTextField( 6 );

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setSize(500,210);
        add(BorderLayout.CENTER, scrollTable );
        add(BorderLayout.SOUTH,  textMe );
        setVisible(true);
    }

    class MyJTable extends JTable
    {
       MyJTable( TableModel model)
       {
          super(model);
       }
//
// Trying to get cells selected when editing starts
       @Override
       public Component prepareEditor(TableCellEditor editor,
                                         int row, int column)
       {
          Component editComponent = super.prepareEditor(editor, row, column);
          if (editComponent instanceof JTextComponent)
          {
             System.out.println( "In prepare editor" );
             ((JTextComponent) editComponent).selectAll();
//           System.out.println( "Requesting Focus" );
//           System.out.println( 
//              ((JTextComponent) editComponent).isFocusable());
//           System.out.println( 
//              ((JTextComponent) editComponent).requestFocusInWindow());
          }
          return editComponent;
       }    
//
// This also works, but end result is the same- when using this, the editor
// does not have focus, so I cannot update the cell just by switching focus
// to another part of the GUI.
//     @Override
//     public boolean editCellAt( int row, int col, EventObject e )
//     {
//        boolean result = super.editCellAt( row, col, e );
//
//        Component editComponent = getEditorComponent();
//        if (  editComponent == null || 
//            !(editComponent instanceof JTextComponent) )
//           return result;
//        if (e instanceof KeyEvent)
//           ((JTextComponent) editComponent).selectAll();
//
//        return result;
//     }
//
    }

    class MyFocusListener implements FocusListener
    {
       @Override
       public void focusGained(FocusEvent e)
       {
          System.out.println("Table has focus");
       }

       @Override
       public void focusLost(FocusEvent e)
       {
          System.out.println("Table lost focus");
          MyJTable        table       = (MyJTable) e.getSource();
          int[]           columns     = table.getSelectedColumns();
//
// I will not be allowing multiple column selection
//
// This is still a problem, as the table IS editing, even though the editor
// does not seem to have focus. This is true whether I am in the case where
// I really have the editor going (in which case the lostFocus of the editor
// nicely cleans things up) or the editor is not really going, and then the
// lostFocus of the editor never triggers.
//        if ( columns.length > 0 && ! table.isEditing() )
          if ( columns.length > 0 )
          {
             TableColumn       tableColumn = table.getColumnModel()
                                                  .getColumn(columns[0]);
             DefaultCellEditor cellEditor  = (DefaultCellEditor)
                                              tableColumn.getCellEditor();
// Does not have focus even when I double click to edit the cell
             if (cellEditor != null && ! cellEditor.getComponent().hasFocus() );
             {
                System.out.println( "Editor focus: " + 
                                     cellEditor.getComponent().hasFocus() );
                if (!cellEditor.stopCellEditing())
                {
                   cellEditor.cancelCellEditing();
                }
             }
          }
       }
    }

    class MyTableModel extends DefaultTableModel
    {

       public MyTableModel(Object rowData[][], Object columnNames[]) {
           super(rowData, columnNames);
       }

       @Override
       public Class getColumnClass(int col) {
          return Double.class;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col)
       {
          return true;
       }
    }

    class MyCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
    {
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
          JTable table, Object value, boolean selected, boolean focus,
          int row, int col) {

          Component renderComponent = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(
             table, value, selected, focus, row, col);
//
// This is called constantly 
//        System.out.println( "In renderer" );

          if ((row % 2) == 0) {
             renderComponent.setBackground(activeDark);
          } else {
             renderComponent.setBackground(activeLight);
          }

          NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
          nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);

          if (value != null)
             System.out.println( "Value: " + value + "; " + value.getClass() );
          super.setText((value == null) ? "" : nf.format(value));
          super.setHorizontalAlignment( SwingConstants.RIGHT );

          return renderComponent;
       }
    }

    class NumberCellEditor extends DefaultCellEditor
    {
       private Double minimum = 0.0;
       private Double value   = null;
       private final  JTextField textField;
       private final  NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();

       public NumberCellEditor()
       {
          super(new JTextField());
          textField = (JTextField) getComponent();
          nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
          textField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
          textField.addFocusListener(new FocusListener()
          {
             @Override
             public void focusGained(FocusEvent e)
             {
                System.out.println( "In editor" );
                if (value != null)
                   textField.setText(nf.format(value.doubleValue()));
                else
                   textField.setText("");
                textField.setCaretPosition(0);
             }

             @Override
             public void focusLost(FocusEvent e)
             {
                System.out.println( "Lost focus editing cell" );
                if (!stopCellEditing()) cancelCellEditing();
             }
           });
        }

        public boolean stopCellEditing()
        {
          String s = (String)super.getCellEditorValue();
          System.out.println( "Stop Cell editing: " + value );
          if ("".equals(s))
          {
             value = null;
             super.stopCellEditing();
          }
          try
          {
              value = nf.parse(s).doubleValue();
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
             textField.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red));
             return false;
          }
          return super.stopCellEditing();
       }

       public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                                                    boolean isSelected,
                                                    int row, int col)
       {
          this.value = (Double) value;
          textField.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
          return super.getTableCellEditorComponent(
                          table, value, isSelected, row, col);
       }

       public Object getCellEditorValue()
       {
          value = (Double) value;
          return value;
       }
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        ExcelTableTest excelTest = new ExcelTableTest();
    }
}
```

Here is the simple solution described below. It only requires one line-

```
        tableMe.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", Boolean.TRUE);
```

If I start typing in a cell, then mouse click in the cell, I go into the editor and lose what was being typed. If I click anywhere else, what was being typed is saved and the editor is stopped.

What I had tried was to define a flag-

```
   private boolean       reallyInEditor = true;
```

then override editCellAt rather than prepare editor

```
       @Override
       public boolean editCellAt( int row, int col, EventObject e )
       {
          boolean result = super.editCellAt( row, col, e );

          Component editComponent = getEditorComponent();
          if (  editComponent == null || 
              !(editComponent instanceof JTextComponent) )
             return result;
          if (e instanceof KeyEvent)
          {
             ((JTextComponent) editComponent).selectAll();
             reallyInEditor = false;
         }

          return result;
       }
    }
```

to set my flag to indicate the user entered the editor by typing rather than a double-click

and put a FocusListener on the table

```
        tableMe.addFocusListener( new MyFocusListener() );

    class MyFocusListener implements FocusListener
    {
       @Override
       public void focusGained(FocusEvent e)
       {
          System.out.println("Table has focus");
       }

       @Override
       public void focusLost(FocusEvent e)
       {
          System.out.println("Table lost focus");
          MyJTable        table       = (MyJTable) e.getSource();
          int[]           columns     = table.getSelectedColumns();
//
// I will not be allowing multiple column selection
          if ( columns.length > 0 )
          {
             TableColumn       tableColumn = table.getColumnModel()
                                                  .getColumn(columns[0]);
             DefaultCellEditor cellEditor  = (DefaultCellEditor)
                                              tableColumn.getCellEditor();
             if (cellEditor != null && !reallyInEditor)
             {
                System.out.println( "Editor focus: " + 
                                     cellEditor.getComponent().hasFocus() );
                if (!cellEditor.stopCellEditing())
                {
                   cellEditor.cancelCellEditing();
                }
                reallyInEditor = true;
             }
          }
       }
    }
```

the difference from all this extra work, is that if I start typing in a cell, then click in the cell, the cell is updated with the value I was entering and the editor is stopped.

Comment: I'm not sitting at my PC right now, but, the focusLost event is more likely to be triggered by the editor, not the table (or at least the one you're interested in). The only arrow keys your going to be really interested in is the down and up arrows, but I'm not sure if that even works in Excel, in any case, you could use key bindings (with ANCESTOR_ OF_FOCUS_OWNER), which should allow you to supply custom key strokes even while the editor is active

Answer (score 4):

Use the following line of code to achieve what you are looking for:

```
tableMe.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost",Boolean.TRUE);
```

Comment: +1 but one should be aware that this is only going to work for the inbuilt editors

Comment: @MadProgrammer - no, it'll work with any editor which is implemented correctly ;-)

Comment: @kleopatra can you define "correctly" cause I've never been able to get it to work :(

Comment: @MadProgrammer "correctly" == any pending edit is terminated when the focus is transfered to a component outside of the table. Which might or not be the OP's problem, re-reading the question ...

Comment: @kleopatra Would that mean it's up to the editor to `stopEditing` when focus is lost or that the table will detect the lost of focus and stop the editor??

Comment: @MadProgrammer it's the table's task - should be, don't know whether or not it's working correctly in core, JXTable has some refinement (which might or not work in corner cases - would be delighted if you have a hard example which doesn't :-)

Comment: I tried this and it worked well. Playing around before getting a more elegant solution, my users usually start editing simply by typing and the table has the focus. So they can use all four arrow keys to move to another cell. Were they to double click, the editor would have focus. The latter case, I was handling. I put a focus listener on the table, tested how the editor was entered(see if event was KeyEvent in editCellAt) and stopCellEditing in that case. A difference using terminateEditorOn FocusLost, if I click in the cell, the partial edit is lost, my kludge updates the cell with new value